# Send Mass Email to account through workflow

Tags: email, workflow

I want to send emails to all "Contact" who are active(field which I used to filter active or non active accounts and HasOptedOutOfEmail equals TRUE) user when an object name "Application" gets created in my org

I want to send it through workflow(no third party packages)

I have created an Email template for that. while creating workflow rules, What should I select in recipient? 
Is it possible through public group??

It would be great if i can get any help or lead as well.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use process builder with flows

Answer (score 0):

Create a formula field on Application say, ContactEmail that is populated dynamically as email of the Contact associated with the Application. 
You an add the condition when creating formula field, that is, 
IF contact is Active etc, then only populate the Email of Contact, ELSE keep the field blank.

And when creating workflow on Application, select this email field in receipient.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for rply.. 
but i want email id of all the contact which are active.. this will give me only one email id